# PLS 00357 Error- Table, View or Sequence "txt.col1" not allowed in the context

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have created one **Stored Procedure**. In that Stored Proc I want if the value of **col1** & **col2** match with employee then insert the unique record of the employee. If not found then match the value of **col1**, **col2** & **col3** with ***employee*** match then insert the value. If also not found while match all these column then insert the record by using another column.
Also one more thing that i want find list of values like **emp_id** by passing the another column value and if a single record can not **match** then make **emp_id** as **NULL**.

```
create or replace procedure sp_ex
AS
empID_in varchar2(10);
fname_in varchar2(20);
lname_in varchar2(30);
---------

type record is ref cursor return txt%rowtype;  --Staging table
v_rc record;
rc rc%rowtype;
begin
 open v_rc for select * from txt;
 loop 
 fetch v_rc into rc;
 exit when v_rc%notfound;
 loop
      select col1 from tbl1
 Where EXISTS (select col1 from tbl1 where tbl1.col1 = rc.col1);

IF txt.col1 = rc.col1 AND txt.col2 = rc.col2 THEN
insert into main_table select distinct * from txt where txt.col2 = rc.col2;

ELSIF txt.col1 = rc.col1 AND txt.col2 = rc.col2 AND txt.col3 = rc.col3 THEN 
insert into main_table select distinct * from txt where txt.col2 = rc.col2;

ELSE 
insert into main_table select * from txt where txt.col4 = rc.col4;
end if;
end loop;
close v_rc;
end sp_ex;
```

I found an error while compile this Store Procedure `PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference not allowed in this context`. How to resolve this issue and how to insert value from staging to main table while using **CASE** or **IF ELSIF** statement. Could you please help me so that i can compile the Stored Proc.

Comment: Your Procedure has two loop keyword but only one end loop that yields the problem.

Comment: I invariably find that laying out code neatly makes some of these issues easier to spot. The first thing I did when looking at this was to fix the case and indentation, and immediately the mismatched `loop`/`end loop` jumped out at me. There are other issues here, but you can start by not making life hard for yourself and for anyone maintaining your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have  your database to work with it's difficult to be 100% certain, but to my eye the line which  reads

```
rc rc%rowtype;
```

should say

```
rc txt%rowtype;
```

You've defined the cursor `v_rc` as returning `txt%rowtype`, and your SQL statement used with this cursor is `select * from txt`, but that data type is at odds with the definition of `rc`. Thus, it appears you need to change `rc` as shown.

It also looks like the `LOOP` statement which comes immediately after `exit when v_rc%notfound;` should be removed, as there's nothing after that which would terminate that loop.

In addition, you have many references to columns in the `txt` table, e.g. `IF txt.col1 = rc.col1`. You can't refer to values in a table in this manner. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here so I can't really suggest anything.

Also, the statement

```
select col1 from tbl1
  Where EXISTS (select col1 from tbl1 where tbl1.col1 = rc.col1);
```

is selecting a column from the database, but isn't putting it anywhere. This should be either a singleton SELECT (`SELECT..INTO`) or a cursor.

One more thing: you can't use `distinct *`. You need to use a column list with `distinct`.

Perhaps the following would be close to what you're trying to do:

```
create or replace procedure sp_ex
AS
begin
  FOR rc IN (SELECT * FROM TXT)
  LOOP
    FOR t1 IN (SELECT *
                 FROM TBL1
                 WHERE TBL1.COL1 = rc.COL1)
    LOOP
      IF t1.COL1 = rc.COL1 AND
         t1.COL2 = rc.COL2
      THEN
        insert into main_table
          select *
            from txt
            where txt.col2 = rc.col2;
      ELSIF t1.col1 = rc.col1 AND
            t1.col2 = rc.col2 AND
            t1.col3 = rc.col3
      THEN 
        insert into main_table
          select *
            from txt
            where txt.col2 = rc.col2;
      ELSE
        insert into main_table
          select *
            from txt
            where txt.col4 = rc.col4;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;  -- t1
  END LOOP;  -- rc
end sp_ex;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: col1 in tbl1 & col1 in txt both are different. Assume col1 in tbl1 as "abc" and col1 in txt as "xyz"